# GeoServer - New Store creation error

Tags: geoserver, windows

I have installed new GeoServer and trying to create new store. Getting this error:

> Error creating data store with the provided parameters: Error persisting DataStoreInfoImpl[Test] to workspaces/cite/Test/datastore.xml

I saw somewhere that this error alerts that the user doesn't have needed access, but I logged in as Admin user therefore should have full rights.

Comment: The user running geoserver doesn't have write permission to the data directory

Comment: Sorry, could you explain in more details, please? I am using Admin user. Isn't it has full permissions?

Comment: The user logging into GeoServer is irrelevant, I'm talking about the user **running** the geoserver program - usually `tomcat` or similar which must have permission to write to the data directory

Comment: Checked. GeoServer/Apache Tomcat is running as Local System so it has enough access to D:\data_dir.

Noticed another strange thing: Logged in to GeoServer page
And was able to login successfully.  However on the logs it show failed.

2023-04-12 06:50:50,400 WARN [geoserver.security] - Failed login, user admin from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
2023-04-12 06:50:50,400 INFO [geoserver.security] - Brute force attack prevention, delaying login for 2577ms

Comment: with tomcat 9 you must explicitly add readwrite permissions for external directories